# Should an MVC application perform DateTime calculations in its views?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a `DaysPastDue` integer property.  It should be calculated based on the number of days past the `DueDate` datetime property.  Should this calculation be done inside of the controller or directly on the view?  Programatically what would that look like?

**Controller.cs**

```
 // GET: myController
        [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var myVariable= myData.Include(moreData);
            return View(myVariable.ToList());
        }
```

**View.cshtml**

```
<table class="table">
<tr>
  <th>
    Due Date
  </th>
  <th>
     Days Past Due
  </th>
</tr>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
     <tr>
       <td>
          @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DueDate)
       </td>
       <td>
          @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DaysPastDue)
       </td>
     </tr>
}
```

Comment: `if (DateTime.Now > DueDate.AddDays(DaysPastDue))` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One good reason *not* to do this date comparison in the view is that you don't want the logic that determines how your application behaves to be scattered across multiple layers of your application. If this logic is built into your controllers or models then it can be reused across multiple views. If it's in the view and you need to recreate a view, that logic will need to be reincorporated.

Also, suppose you determine that your "days past due" needs some particular logic to account for hours, weekends, etc. Now, in addition to having that logic in one place, you may also want to be able to write unit tests for it. That's trivially easy if the logic is in the right place, but much more difficult if it's in a view.

One of the nice aspects about MVC is that you can write a controller and models  then someone else less familiar with the internal logic can build or maintain the view. The UI developer who is great at making your page look awesome shouldn't have to worry about messing up the "days past due" logic.

There's even something to be said for avoiding direct references to `DateTime.Now` because it makes testing more difficult. Every time you create test data you have to adjust the dates according to the current date/time. It's often preferable to inject an interface like this:

```
public interface IDateTimeProvider
{
    DateTime Now { get; }
}
```

Your concrete implementation might look like this:

```
public class DateTimeProvider : IDateTimeProvider
{
    public DateTime Now => DateTime.Now;
}
```

But when testing you can use a [Mock](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart) like

```
var dateTimeMock = new Mock<IDateTimeProvider>();
dateTimeMock.Setup(x => x.Now).Returns(DateTime.Parse("5/21/2018"));
```

Or you could create a test double like

```
public class DateTimeProviderDouble : IDateTimeProvider
{
    public DateTimeProviderDouble(DateTime provides)
    {
        Now = provides;
    }
    public DateTime Now { get; private set; }
}

var dateTimeProvider = new DateTimeProviderDouble(DateTime.Parse("6/21/2018"));
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I suspected this logic should be done in the controller but your answer really pointed out why that is.

Answer (score 1):

`Should this calculation be done inside of the controller or directly on the view`  Generally speaking your controller and / or model does calculations.  As much as possible you want your view just deciding how to present the data it receives.  Just because you CAN write a bunch of code to do stuff in a view doesn't mean you SHOULD.

Comment: Finishing my thought -- it's (usually) fairly easy to write a unit test for a Controller or a Model.  For a view, possible yes, but it has passed beyond my definition of easy.